# OleDB Parameter not updating properly

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

```
con.Open();
com.Connection = con;
String query2 = "update PointCard set Player_User=@a where PC_Pass=@b";
com.CommandText = query2;

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("a", txtUser.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("b", txtPass.Text));
MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your continuous support");
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();



con.Open();
com.Connection = con;
String query1 = "update PointCard set PC_Status=@x where PC_Pass=@y";
com.CommandText = query1;

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("x", txtInactive.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("y", txtPass.Text));
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("PointCard " + txtPass.Text + " has been credited to your account");
con.Close();
```

I learned from my previous question to use parameterized queries and now I'm here again confused.

The problem I'm encountering is that somehow `PC_Status` in the Access table is ending up with the values from `txtUser.Text` after executing the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying data provider is using positional parameters? Since you're reusing the `com` variable for another command, the previous parameters are still present in the parameters collection. Also, there is no need to close and reopen the connection, just open it before executing the first command, and close it after executing the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you re-define your `CommandText` property with `query1`, your parameters collection that you added for `query2` are *still* part of your command.

Changing `CommandText` property of an `OleDbCommand` doesn't clear or effect it's [`OleDbParameterCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They will be *still* part of that command.

Just clear them when you add your new parameters like;

```
com.Parameters.Clear();
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("x", txtInactive.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("y", txtPass.Text));
```

Or you can create a new `SqlCommand` object for your second query like;

```
String query1 = "update PointCard set PC_Status=@x where PC_Pass=@y";
var com = new OleDbCommand();
com.CommandText = query1;
...
...
```

Also please use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of `Close` methods manually.